# How to refresh yii2 frontend validation for the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, yii2

I have got the form and I do some things after validate with ajax on the page. I do it with `.on('afterValidate', function ()` And all works good, but only first time. After it form is not working, if I will work with it second time. How I can refresh frontend validation and work with this form again and again on submit? Just `.on('submit'` - is not good idea, because form works twice in this mode (form submitted two times, because validation from backend will be).

Answer (score 0):

I think for AJAX-based validation you should use another event:

**ajaxComplete** event is triggered after completing an AJAX request for AJAX-based validation.
The signature of the event handler should be:

```
function (event, jqXHR, textStatus)
```

where

- `event`: an Event object
- `jqXHR`: a jqXHR object
- `settings`: the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").

Can't find it in official docs, you can see it [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js) in `var = events { ... }`

So try `.on('ajaxComplete', function (event, jqXHR, textStatus) { ... })` instead of `.on('afterValidate', function ({ ... })`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My form works without ajax yii settings. I just create form.preventDefault() and after it do some code and send ajax to backend. My customer wants to see "on fly" profile edit

Comment: can you also take look on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154544/how-to-solve-bad-request-400-unable-to-verify-your-data-submission-in-yii2

Comment: How to switch on yii ajax validation?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Validating when switching between fields?