# How to solve Bad Request (#400) Unable to verify your data submission in yii2?

Tags: forms, yii2, active-form

I have got this error, when submit the form:

> ```
> Bad Request (#400) Unable to verify your data submission.
> ```

I have got `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>` in the layout. I think, that this problems I have, because I use datepicker. Form create with ActiveForm.

What I must to do? Here is code of the form:

```
<?
        $form2 = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'user-univer']);
        echo $form2->field($model2, 'university')->label('Input university name:');
        echo $form2->field($model2, 'degree')->label('Input your education specialization:');
        //echo $form2->field($model2, 'date')->label('Input your education date:');
        echo '<label class="control-label">Education time:</label><br/>';
        echo '<span>Start date of your education:</span>';
        echo DatePicker::widget([
            'name'  => 'date_from',
            'value'  => $value,
            'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
        ]);
        echo '<span>End date of your education:</span>';
        echo DatePicker::widget([
            'name'  => 'date_to',
            'value'  => $value,
            'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',    
        ]);
        echo '<br/><br/>';


        echo $form2->field($model2, 'info')->textarea()->label('Any other information about your university degree:');
        echo Html::submitButton('Add university', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-univer']);
        ActiveForm::end(['id' => 'user-univer']);

        } ?>
```

**UPD:** without datepicker I have got the same problems, why? how to solve it?

Comment: In output html in form set input like `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf">`?

Comment: @vitalik_74 , yes, I have got this hidden input with long value, looks like base64

Comment: show us your controller behavior

Answer (score 2):

Add csrf token field in your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfParam?>" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />
```

Will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

problem may be due to csrf validation. Have you tried disabling csrf Validation

inside action try this

```
$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

[check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526873/disable-csrf-validation-for-individual-actions-in-yii2)

Comment: This is last resort actually.

Comment: no one provided him any other answer, so i thought i should give him this option

Answer (score 0):

I found that is missing a `/` in the end of input, ex:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="bWs1ZlJSeGYiHG0xNThVNgBYBzY8FAI5PS4CVn8lJzMeIkAgKgU0Ig==">
```

Working input is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="bWs1ZlJSeGYiHG0xNThVNgBYBzY8FAI5PS4CVn8lJzMeIkAgKgU0Ig==" />
```

In my case I modified `yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseHtml`:

```
public static function tag($name, $content = '', $options = [])
{
    if ($name === null || $name === false) {
        return $content;
    }
    if ($name=="input") {$html = "<$name" . static::renderTagAttributes($options) . '/>';}
    else {$html = "<$name" . static::renderTagAttributes($options) . '>';      }

    return isset(static::$voidElements[strtolower($name)]) ? $html : "$html$content</$name>";
}
```